# Android Studio projects are having an error "Missing Permission"

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, android-manifest

Note: I was working on the project and building it from time to time. It was working fine, until recently all of my projects started showing a "missing permission error" but I've mentioned permission in the AndroidManifest file already for the projects.

Project 1 :

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        ////other code

</manifest>
```

[missing permission error in first project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAatK.png)

Why I need permission / permission check:

[error-at(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVeSu.png)

[error-at(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ3HX.png)

[error-at(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDt2J.png)

[error-at(4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaMUJ.png)

[missing permission error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxypZ.png)

build.gradle (:app) (first project):

```
dependencies {
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:3.0.0'
}
```

Same error occurs in my second project.

Second Project:
[missing permission error in second project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZc8Y.png)

AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.driver">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
//other stuff
```

The Project builds log:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 90 ms

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguid/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 34s
```

What happens if I run this project with the error:
It doesn't asks for my permission but shows the permission in the Setting -> Apps
[permission showing in the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvJuf.jpg)

What I already tried:

1. Rebuilding the project
2. Cleaning the project
3. Upgrading the Gradle
4. Deleting the project and building the backup version(one commit revert as I use github)

Comment: You need to request permission

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of research and trying new things out, I found out that my AndroidManifest.xml was not merging files and it was happening for all of my projects.

I can't find the answer to why it was happening but it was the reason why the permission inside the AndroidManifest.xml was not working.

The things I did to solve that issue

1. Delete the Android Studio directory at E:/Android Studio (custom)
2. Delete the .android directory at C:/Users/UserName/.android (default)
3. Delete the .gradle directory at C:/Users/UserName/.gradle (default)
4. Install new Android Studio

After that all the previous projects were working fine

Note:
To view the Directory (e.g .android) make sure that "show hidden files/folders" is enabled

Comment: You right; This Manifest merger was unable to merge all manifests. I had to fix my manifests inside modules. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy fix, Android studio will automatically generate some code with return statement. Which will check the permission if  granted then, the next line of code will be executed else you ask permission at runtime  if granted and rerun the same yourgetLocationmethod();

[This link will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time)

[image]

Comment: This question is about Android Studio giving the warning even if the permission is already in the manifest.