# Android Manifest permissions issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have an app where im using `uses-permission` tags in the **AndroidManifest.xml** to give some permissions to my app, eg *CAMERA*. But when i check the permissions through my phone's settings all the given permissions are denied and i have to manually change it to allow. What could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Those are called run-time permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time

Answer (score 0):

In higher Android versions the user needs to allow the permissions.
You must to show a dialog asking about the permissions

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: The link is an incomplete answer, since the resource may be deleted. Please complete the answer with an example of usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since android 12 granting permissions in manifest isn't enough imo. Check out: 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting