# Programmatically determine if Android app has system-level permission

Tags: android, permissions

I'm building an app for gathering and displaying detailed usage statistics (for science!) that uses the `android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager` system service. This service requires the *system-level* permission `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`.

The user needs to explicitly grant system-level permissions under Settings. When the app is launched, I want to programmatically determine if the app has been already been granted this permission. If not, I want to display a prompt like this:

[image: Permission prompt]

To check if an app has a required permission, I would usually do something like this:

```
if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED == checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS")) {
    // display prompt
}

// keep going
```

The prompt launches the `Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS` intent:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

[image: App clearly has permission]

However, the call to `checkCallingOrSelfPermission(String)` consistently returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` (a.k.a `-1`) even when the app already has been granted this permission.

Is there a special way of checking for system-level permissions, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: This question has been answered here I think : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203668/how-permission-can-be-checked-at-runtime-without-throwing-securityexception

Comment: @Martin Lehmann Exactly, the answer in the above-mentioned does not work in this case. However, did you come up with a solution

Comment: @7geeky I did not! I abandoned this project shortly after writing this question, terribly sorry…

Comment: @MartinLehmann thanks man. I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28921586/2900127) would be helpful for any future use