# Android marshmallow request permission?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am currently working on an application that requires several "dangerous" permissions. So I tried adding "ask for permission" as required in Android Marshmallow(API Level 23), but couldn't find how to do it.

How can I ask for permission using new permission model in my app?

Comment: Have a look here, this is all you need: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Have a look to this http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: Did you look at the samples on Google's GitHub repo?

Comment: saw from developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html, at that time i was new to android and soon android Marshmallow came and google's training made me more confused, and was unable to find any tutorial regarding this

Comment: I have created library for it. It is easy to use by simple steps. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52708289/4961126

Comment: Another alternative https://medium.com/@hiteshkrsahu/android-easy-permissions-for-devs-84da87f32a83

Answer (score 294, accepted):

[Request runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) from the docs has code examples you can use.

The code snippets in this answer are taken from that document.

Open a Dialog using the code below:

> ```
> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
>                     new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
>                     1);
> ```

Get the Activity result as below:

> ```
> @Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>                                        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case 1: {
>
>           // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>           if (grantResults.length > 0
>                     && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>                 // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                 // contacts-related task you need to do.          
>             } else {
>
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'case' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     } }
> ```

More info: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: also this part for if user clicked cancel: else if (grantResults.length > 0                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)

Comment: is `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` deprecated? (in Nugat)

Comment: where do you get that variable? ActivityCompat ?

Comment: @gumuruh, what variable?

Comment: This works for seemingly everything else but for. "Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" as it is a protected permission. Can anybody help? I am using Oreo.

Comment: @AMITAVA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472398/how-to-use-storagestatsmanager-querystatsforpackage-on-android-o

Comment: @DixitPanchal , Thanks!, I did not try it yet, but the discussion in the following helped to get permission. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921136

Answer (score 67):

This structure I am using to check if my app has permission and than request if it does not have permission. So in my main code from where i want to check write following :

```
int MyVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (MyVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                if (!checkIfAlreadyhavePermission()) {
                    requestForSpecificPermission();
                }
}
```

Module checkIfAlreadyhavePermission() is implemented as :

```
private boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Module requestForSpecificPermission() is implemented as :

```
private void requestForSpecificPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
}
```

and Override in Activity :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 101:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //granted
            } else {
                //not granted
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Refer this link for more details : http://revisitingandroid.blogspot.in/2017/01/how-to-check-and-request-for-run-time.html

Comment: Friendly suggestion: Replace the if statement in `checkIfAlreadyhavePermission` to `return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;`

Answer (score 20):

Starting in Android Marshmallow, we need to request the user for specific permissions. We can also check through code if the permission is already given. Here is a list of commonly needed permissions:

> - **android.permission_group.CALENDAR**
>
>   - android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
>   - android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
> - **android.permission_group.CAMERA**
>
>   - android.permission.CAMERA
> - **android.permission_group.CONTACTS**
>
>   - android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
>   - android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>   - android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
> - **android.permission_group.LOCATION**
>
>   - android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
>   - android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> - **android.permission_group.MICROPHONE**
>
>   - android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
> - **android.permission_group.PHONE**
>
>   - android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
>   - android.permission.CALL_PHONE
>   - android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
>   - android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
>   - android.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL
>   - android.permission.USE_SIP
>   - android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
> - **android.permission_group.SENSORS**
>
>   - android.permission.BODY_SENSORS
> - **android.permission_group.SMS**
>
>   - android.permission.SEND_SMS
>   - android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
>   - android.permission.READ_SMS
>   - android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
>   - android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS
>   - android.permission.READ_CELL_BROADCASTS
> - **android.permission_group.STORAGE**
>
>   - android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   - android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Here is sample code to check for permissions:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setMessage("Write calendar permission is necessary to write event!!!");
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
            }
        });
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I have used this wrapper (Recommended) written by google developers. Its super easy to use.

https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

Function dealing with checking and ask for permission if required

```
public void locationAndContactsTask() {
    String[] perms = { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS };
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
        // Have permissions, do the thing!
        Toast.makeText(this, "TODO: Location and Contacts things", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // Ask for both permissions
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.rationale_location_contacts),
                RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERM, perms);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Farhan I understood that :) I only wish that Android's API would be easier so we wouldn't have to use wrappers.

Comment: i cant see where the "RC_CAMERA_AND_LOCATION" comes from, or where to find other permissions instead of those, do you know where that comes from?

Answer (score 16):

My class for request runtime permissions in `Activity` or `Fragment`

It also help you show **rationale** or open **Setting** to enable permission after user denied a permission (with/without `Never ask again`) option easier

```
class RequestPermissionHandler(private val activity: Activity? = null,
                               private val fragment: Fragment? = null,
                               private val permissions: Set<String> = hashSetOf(),
                               private val listener: Listener? = null
) {
    private var hadShowRationale: Boolean = false

    fun requestPermission() {
        hadShowRationale = showRationaleIfNeed()
        if (!hadShowRationale) {
            doRequestPermission(permissions)
        }
    }

    fun retryRequestDeniedPermission() {
        doRequestPermission(permissions)
    }

    private fun showRationaleIfNeed(): Boolean {
        val unGrantedPermissions = getPermission(permissions, Status.UN_GRANTED)
        val permanentDeniedPermissions = getPermission(unGrantedPermissions, Status.PERMANENT_DENIED)
        if (permanentDeniedPermissions.isNotEmpty()) {
            val consume = listener?.onShowSettingRationale(unGrantedPermissions)
            if (consume != null && consume) {
                return true
            }
        }

        val temporaryDeniedPermissions = getPermission(unGrantedPermissions, Status.TEMPORARY_DENIED)
        if (temporaryDeniedPermissions.isNotEmpty()) {
            val consume = listener?.onShowPermissionRationale(temporaryDeniedPermissions)
            if (consume != null && consume) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    fun requestPermissionInSetting() {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
        val packageName = activity?.packageName ?: run {
            fragment?.requireActivity()?.packageName
        }
        val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
        intent.data = uri
        activity?.apply {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
        } ?: run {
            fragment?.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                   grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            for (i in grantResults.indices) {
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    markNeverAskAgainPermission(permissions[i], false)
                } else if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[i])) {
                    markNeverAskAgainPermission(permissions[i], true)
                }
            }
            var hasShowRationale = false
            if (!hadShowRationale) {
                hasShowRationale = showRationaleIfNeed()
            }
            if (hadShowRationale || !hasShowRationale) {
                notifyComplete()
            }
        }
    }

    fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            getPermission(permissions, Status.GRANTED).forEach {
                markNeverAskAgainPermission(it, false)
            }
            notifyComplete()
        }
    }

    fun cancel() {
        notifyComplete()
    }

    private fun doRequestPermission(permissions: Set<String>) {
        activity?.let {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(it, permissions.toTypedArray(), REQUEST_CODE)
        } ?: run {
            fragment?.requestPermissions(permissions.toTypedArray(), REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    private fun getPermission(permissions: Set<String>, status: Status): Set<String> {
        val targetPermissions = HashSet<String>()
        for (p in permissions) {
            when (status) {
                Status.GRANTED -> {
                    if (isPermissionGranted(p)) {
                        targetPermissions.add(p)
                    }
                }
                Status.TEMPORARY_DENIED -> {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(p)) {
                        targetPermissions.add(p)
                    }
                }
                Status.PERMANENT_DENIED -> {
                    if (isNeverAskAgainPermission(p)) {
                        targetPermissions.add(p)
                    }
                }
                Status.UN_GRANTED -> {
                    if (!isPermissionGranted(p)) {
                        targetPermissions.add(p)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return targetPermissions
    }

    private fun isPermissionGranted(permission: String): Boolean {
        return activity?.let {
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        } ?: run {
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(fragment!!.requireActivity(), permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
    }

    private fun shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission: String): Boolean {
        return activity?.let {
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(it, permission)
        } ?: run {
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(fragment!!.requireActivity(), permission)
        }
    }

    private fun notifyComplete() {
        listener?.onComplete(getPermission(permissions, Status.GRANTED), getPermission(permissions, Status.UN_GRANTED))
    }

    private fun getPrefs(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS_RUNTIME_PERMISSION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    private fun isNeverAskAgainPermission(permission: String): Boolean {
        return getPrefs(requireContext()).getBoolean(permission, false)
    }

    private fun markNeverAskAgainPermission(permission: String, value: Boolean) {
        getPrefs(requireContext()).edit().putBoolean(permission, value).apply()
    }

    private fun requireContext(): Context {
        return fragment?.requireContext() ?: run {
            activity!!
        }
    }

    enum class Status {
        GRANTED, UN_GRANTED, TEMPORARY_DENIED, PERMANENT_DENIED
    }

    interface Listener {
        fun onComplete(grantedPermissions: Set<String>, deniedPermissions: Set<String>)
        fun onShowPermissionRationale(permissions: Set<String>): Boolean
        fun onShowSettingRationale(permissions: Set<String>): Boolean
    }

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_CODE = 200
    }
}
```

Using in `Activity` like

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var smsAndStoragePermissionHandler: RequestPermissionHandler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        smsAndStoragePermissionHandler = RequestPermissionHandler(this@MainActivity,
                permissions = setOf(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                listener = object : RequestPermissionHandler.Listener {
                    override fun onComplete(grantedPermissions: Set<String>, deniedPermissions: Set<String>) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        text_granted.text = "Granted: " + grantedPermissions.toString()
                        text_denied.text = "Denied: " + deniedPermissions.toString()
                    }

                    override fun onShowPermissionRationale(permissions: Set<String>): Boolean {
                        AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity).setMessage("To able to Send Photo, we need SMS and" + " Storage permission")
                                .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                                    smsAndStoragePermissionHandler.retryRequestDeniedPermission()
                                }
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                                    smsAndStoragePermissionHandler.cancel()
                                    dialog.dismiss()
                                }
                                .show()
                        return true // don't want to show any rationale, just return false here
                    }

                    override fun onShowSettingRationale(permissions: Set<String>): Boolean {
                        AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity).setMessage("Go Settings -> Permission. " + "Make SMS on and Storage on")
                                .setPositiveButton("Settings") { _, _ ->
                                    smsAndStoragePermissionHandler.requestPermissionInSetting()
                                }
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                                    smsAndStoragePermissionHandler.cancel()
                                    dialog.cancel()
                                }
                                .show()
                        return true
                    }
                })

        button_request.setOnClickListener { handleRequestPermission() }
    }

    private fun handleRequestPermission() {
        smsAndStoragePermissionHandler.requestPermission()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        smsAndStoragePermissionHandler.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        smsAndStoragePermissionHandler.onActivityResult(requestCode)
    }
}
```

[Code on Github](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidRequestPermissionProgrammatically)

[Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuqzalt5-MM)

Comment: best solution about ask permission which I could find

Comment: @Phan, do you have a code snippet requesting permission and handling not handling

Comment: This code seems to be in kotlin. Any java version available?

Answer (score 13):

Android-M ie, API 23 introduced [Runtime Permissions](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) for reducing security flaws in android device, where users can now directly manage app permissions at runtime.so if the user denies a particular permission of your application you have to obtain it by asking the permission dialog that you mentioned in your query.

So check before action ie, check you have permission to access the resource [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check) and if your application doesn't have that particular permission you can request the permission [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request) and handle the the permissions request response like below.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

               } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

So finally, It's a good practice to go through [behavior changes](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) if you are planning to work with new versions to avoid force closes :)

[Permissions Best Practices.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/best-practices.html)

You can go through the official sample app [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/RuntimePermissions/index.html).

Comment: Please bear in mind **we must have noHistory=false** in order to receive callback. Also refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33080682/1911652) in case if you don't receive callback. I wasted hours to figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

Add the permissions to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application ...>
 ....
</application>
```

To check the Android version if it needs runtime permission or not.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    askForPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 1);
}
```

Ask the user to grant the permission if not granted.

```
private void askForPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Please grant the requested permission to get your task done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Do something if the permission was granted or not.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //permission with request code 1 granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //permission with request code 1 was not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission was not Granted" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

From Android Marshmallow(API 23) and above by default all dangerous permission ( as per official doc [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html)) disabled. After installation when app open first time then you have to grant permission at Run Time.

I achieved this following way:

```
public class MarshMallowPermission {

    public static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_BY_GALLERY = 0;
    public static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_BY_CAMERA = 1;
    public static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_BY_LOAD_PROFILE = 2;
    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
    public static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 4;
    Activity activity;
    Context mContext;

    public MarshMallowPermission(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mContext = activity;
    }

    public boolean checkPermissionForExternalStorage(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissionForCamera(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){

        int result = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissionForExternalStorage(int requestCode){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},requestCode);
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissionForCamera(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
            Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Camera permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
    public void requestPermissionForLocation(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)){
            Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Location permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

IN Your activity class:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   private MarshMallowPermission marshMallowPermission;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("NavHome", "Oncreate_nav");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        marshMallowPermission = new MarshMallowPermission(MainActivity.this);



        if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
            marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage(MarshMallowPermission.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_BY_LOAD_PROFILE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MarshMallowPermission.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_BY_LOAD_PROFILE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //permission granted successfully

                } else {

                 //permission denied

                }
                break;
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this as a base Fragment class. I only ask for permissions from a fragment, but you could refactor it and make a similar Activity version.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_BLOCK_INTERNAL = 555;
    private static final String PERMISSION_SHARED_PREFERENCES = "permissions";

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_BLOCK_INTERNAL) {
            boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;

            for (int iGranting : grantResults) {
                if (iGranting != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    allPermissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (allPermissionsGranted && permissionBlock != null) {
                permissionBlock.run();
            }

            permissionBlock = null;
        }
    }

    public void runNowOrAskForPermissionsFirst(String permission, Runnable block) {
        if (hasPermission(permission)) {
            block.run();
        } else if (!hasPermissionOrWillAsk(permission)) {
            permissionBlock = block;
            askForPermission(permission, PERMISSION_REQUEST_BLOCK_INTERNAL);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasPermissionOrWillAsk(String permission) {
        boolean hasPermission = hasPermission(permission);
        boolean hasAsked = hasPreviouslyAskedForPermission(permission);
        boolean shouldExplain = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission);

        return hasPermission || (hasAsked && !shouldExplain);
    }

    private boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private boolean hasPreviouslyAskedForPermission(String permission) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PERMISSION_SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getBoolean(permission, false);
    }

    private void askForPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PERMISSION_SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        editor.putBoolean(permission, true);
        editor.apply();

        requestPermissions(new String[] { permission }, requestCode);
    }
}
```

There are two key methods you should use:

- hasPermissionOrWillAsk - Use this to see if a permission has been asked for and denies by a user who doesn't want to be asked again. This is useful for disabling UI when the user has given their final answer about NOT wanting a feature.
- runNowOrAskForPermissionsFirst - Use this to run some code that requires permissions. If the user has already granted permission, the code will run immediately. Otherwise, the code will run later if the user grants permission. Or not at all. It's nice because you specify the code in one place.

Here's an example:

```
mFragment.runNowOrAskForPermissionsFirst(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...do something if we have permission...
    }
});
```

Happy to get feedback on this.  Not that this specific example is a little simplified in that you also need to check to see if Location Services are enabled on the device. (That's different than permissions.) Also, it only supports one permission at a time, but would be simple to modify if you need it to support more than one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

To handle runtime permission google has provided a library project. You can check this from here https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

EasyPermissions is installed by adding the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
}
```

To begin using EasyPermissions, have your Activity (or Fragment) override the onRequestPermissionsResult method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    // Forward results to EasyPermissions
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Some permissions have been granted
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Some permissions have been denied
    // ...
}
}
```

Here you will get a working example how this library works
https://github.com/milon87/EasyPermission

Answer (score 4):

It may be a cleaner way. Add all your permissions in an array like

```
private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS={
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    };
    private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST=1337;
```

Whatever your permision is create method for each permision

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessFineLocation() {
    return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessCoarseLocation() {
    return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION));
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
    return(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkSelfPermission(perm));
}
```

Call this method in **onCreate**

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
      if(!canAccessCoarseLocation() || !canAccessFineLocation()){
            requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, INITIAL_REQUEST);
        }
 }
```

Now override **onRequestPermissionsResult**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode == INITIAL_REQUEST){
        if (canAccessFineLocation() && canAccessCoarseLocation())  {
            //call your method
        }
        else {
            //show Toast or alert that this permissions is neccessary
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there was no requireApi and i got Error in my activity i use TragetApi annotation

Comment: @Jawad, this works but better if you add some denied permission callbacks

Answer (score 4):

**If you're using [AndroidX Activity 1.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity) or [AndroidX Fragment 1.3.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment)**:

There are new Activity Result APIs that you can use to ask for permissions:

```
val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
    if (isGranted) {
        // Permission granted. Do the tasks.
    }
}
launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

Comment: Warning! As of 9/2020 both libraries are still alpha.

Comment: still no't stable so i dont recommend this feature.

Answer (score 3):

For multiple permission at a time you can use this. This work for me..  I got another solution. if you give your targetSdkVersion bellow 22 it works for me. and it behavior as like getting permission from manifest.xml. Tested and works for me.

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

    private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

        final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            permissionsNeeded.add("GPS");
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
            permissionsNeeded.add("Read Contacts");
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS))
            permissionsNeeded.add("Write Contacts");

        if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
            if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
                // Need Rationale
                String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
                for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                    message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
                showMessageOKCancel(message,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }

        insertDummyContact();
    }

    private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }






@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
                {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                // Initial
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with results
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // All Permissions Granted
                    insertDummyContact();
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

For more details. Check bellow link

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: setting targetSdkVersion bellow 22 will work, but what will happen in a user using android M denies one permission from settings?

Comment: Yea.. you are right for this time apps will be crash. so that, that time you need to check again permission denies or not from user.. i don't test it but i wish it will work. form every action from user it will be better to check permission is granted or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good library that can be used in case permissions need to be asked when permission is needed by a background service. Although a limitation of library is that it can not be used to just determine whether permissions are currently given to the app or not. It always asks the user if app doesn't already have them.

Do give it a try as it makes life simpler: [Android Permissions](https://github.com/nishkarsh/android-permissions/)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

This is the simplest way to ask for permission in Marshmallow version.

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&&ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        //TO do here if permission is granted by user
    }
    else
    {
        //ask for permission if user didnot given
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }
    }
```

**Note:-** Don't forget to add this same permission in manifest file also

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Second Method**
Code for checking the permission is granted or not?

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
```

And override the method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         //                    grantResult[0] means it will check for the first postion permission which is READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        //                    grantResult[1] means it will check for the Second postion permission which is CAMERA
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you are saying that if I target Marshmallow or above then I don't need to declare permission in manifest? I knew we have to put it regardless of android version we are targeting. Please correct me if I am wrong @Sunil

Comment: @Nilabja declaring permission in manifest is compulsory for all android version weather it is marshmallow or not

Answer (score 2):

This code below works perfectly.I am explaining with the help of an  example.

In my case i placed the permission checks separately in a util class and passed the specific permissions i need to check from the appropriate classes.This enabled to reuse the permission check util file in the whole application.

The below code part shows the function call.In this case am requesting `android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

```
//the below call is from a fragment
     @OnClick(R.id.button)//butterknife implementation
        public void attachPressed() {
            if (PermissionUtils.hasThisPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                onAttachPressed();
            } else {
                PermissionUtils.isPermissionRequestNeeded(getActivity(), this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PermissionUtils.REQUEST_GROUP_STORAGE);
            }
        }
```

In the above case permission is checked if it is allowed the `onAttachPressed();` function is called else we check request permission.

The below is the code present in the util class in my case `PermissionUtils`

```
public final class PermissionUtils {

    public static final int REQUEST_GROUP_STORAGE = 1508;

    private PermissionUtils() {
    }

    public static boolean hasThisPermission(Context context, String permission) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPermissionRequestNeeded(Activity activity, Fragment fragment, String permission, int requestCode) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !hasThisPermission(activity, permission)) {
            final String[] permissions = new String[]{permission};
            if (fragment == null) {
                activity.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
            } else {
                fragment.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And after the request if you might want to call the function from `onRequestPermissionsResult` or else you will need to press the button again for the function call.

So just call it from `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
//the below call  is from a fragment
     @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == PermissionUtils.REQUEST_GROUP_STORAGE && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                onAttachPressed();
            } else {
                Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [**RxPermission**](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) library library for asking permission. Because it is long code which we have to write to ask permission.

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this); // where this is an Activity instance // Must be done during an initialization phase like onCreate
rxPermissions
    .request(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    .subscribe(granted -> {
        if (granted) { // Always true pre-M
           // I can control the camera now
        } else {
           // Oups permission denied
        }
    });
```

Add these dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I went through all answers, but doesn't satisfied my exact needed answer, so here is an example that I wrote and perfectly works, even user clicks the *Don't ask again* checkbox.

1. Create a method that will be called when you want to ask for runtime permission like `readContacts()` or you can also have `openCamera()` as shown below:

   ```
    private void readContacts() {
        if (!askContactsPermission()) {
            return;
        } else {
            queryContacts();
        } }
   ```

Now we need to make `askContactsPermission()`, you can also name it as `askCameraPermission()` or whatever permission you are going to ask.

```
    private boolean askContactsPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        Snackbar.make(parentLayout, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    }
                }).show();
    } else if (contactPermissionNotGiven) {
        openPermissionSettingDialog();
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        contactPermissionNotGiven = true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Before writing this function make sure you have defined the below instance variable as shown:

```
    private View parentLayout;
    private boolean contactPermissionNotGiven;;


/**
 * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
 */
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;
```

Now final step to override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method as shown below:

```
/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            queryContacts();
        }
    }
}
```

Here we are done with the RunTime permissions, the addon is the `openPermissionSettingDialog()` which simply open the Setting screen if user have permanently disable the permission by clicking *Don't ask again* checkbox. below is the method:

```
    private void openPermissionSettingDialog() {
    String message = getString(R.string.message_permission_disabled);
    AlertDialog alertDialog =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                    intent.setData(uri);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            }).show();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
}
```

What we missed ?

1. Defining the used strings in `strings.xml`

```html
<string name="permission_rationale">"Contacts permissions are needed to display Contacts."</string>
    <string name="message_permission_disabled">You have disabled the permissions permanently,
        To enable the permissions please go to Settings -> Permissions and enable the required Permissions,
        pressing OK you will be navigated to Settings screen</string>
```

2. Initializing the `parentLayout` variable inside `onCreate` method

   parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.content);
3. Defining the required permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

4. The `queryContacts` method, based on your need or the runtime permission you can call your method before which the `permission` was needed. in my case I simply use the loader to fetch the contact as shown below:

   ```
    private void queryContacts() {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to ask permission by avoiding writing lots of code,

https://github.com/sachinvarma/EasyPermission

How to add :

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

implementation 'com.github.sachinvarma:EasyPermission:1.0.1'
```

How to ask permission:

```
 List<String> permission = new ArrayList<>();
 permission.add(EasyPermissionList.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
 permission.add(EasyPermissionList.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

 new EasyPermissionInit(MainActivity.this, permission);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solutions from my old code and it's really works good, still working on my Latest Apps.

Put it on MainActivity Class or on your Start Activity Class

```
private RequestPermissionHandler mRequestPermissionHandler;
```

On Create

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   mRequestPermissionHandler = new RequestPermissionHandler();
   handleButtonClicked();
}
```

Private function handleButtonClicked()

```
private void handleButtonClicked() {
        mRequestPermissionHandler.requestPermission(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK

        }, 123, new RequestPermissionHandler.RequestPermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "request permission success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "request permission failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

RequestPermissionHandler.java Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class RequestPermissionHandler {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private RequestPermissionListener mRequestPermissionListener;
    private int mRequestCode;

    public void requestPermission(Activity activity, @NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode,
                                  RequestPermissionListener listener) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mRequestCode = requestCode;
        mRequestPermissionListener = listener;

        if (!needRequestRuntimePermissions()) {
            mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
            return;
        }
        requestUnGrantedPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }

    private boolean needRequestRuntimePermissions() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
    }

    private void requestUnGrantedPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
        String[] unGrantedPermissions = findUnGrantedPermissions(permissions);
        if (unGrantedPermissions.length == 0) {
            mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, unGrantedPermissions, requestCode);
    }

    private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, permission)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private String[] findUnGrantedPermissions(String[] permissions) {
        List<String> unGrantedPermissionList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (!isPermissionGranted(permission)) {
                unGrantedPermissionList.add(permission);
            }
        }
        return unGrantedPermissionList.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == mRequestCode) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                    if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mRequestPermissionListener.onFailed();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
            } else {
                mRequestPermissionListener.onFailed();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface RequestPermissionListener {
        void onSuccess();

        void onFailed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (CommonMethod.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            //showing dialog to select image
                            callFacebook();
                            Log.e("permission", "granted MarshMallow");
                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("permission", "Not Required Less than MarshMallow Version");
                        callFacebook();
                    }
                } else {
                    CommonMethod.showAlert("Internet Connectivity Failure", MainActivity.this);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library — [NoPermission](https://github.com/NoNews/NoPermission) (It's just one class)

`compile 'ru.alexbykov:nopermission:1.1.1'`

**Sample**

```
PermissionHelper permissionHelper = new PermissionHelper(this); //don't use getActivity in fragment!

permissionHelper.check(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                .onSuccess(this::onSuccess)
                .onDenied(this::onDenied)
                .onNeverAskAgain(this::onNeverAskAgain)
                .run();
```

**onRequestPermissionResult:**

```
 @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
        permissionHelper.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
   }
```

I think api more convenient than `EasyPermissions` by Google.

Answer (score 0):

**Runtime Permission AnyWhere In Application**[Here is Example](https://github.com/irshadsparky/PermissionExample)

```
use dependency
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
dependencies {
implementation 'com.github.irshadsparky:PermissionLib:master-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

and call code like this :

```
PermissionHelper.requestCamera(new PermissionHelper.OnPermissionGrantedListener() {
@Override
public void onPermissionGranted() {

}
});
```

you can find more [Github](https://github.com/irshadsparky/PermissionExample)

Answer (score 0):

Run time permission creates a lot of boilerplate code in activity which is heavily coupled. To reduce code and make the thing easy, you can use [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) library.

Answer (score 0):

RUNTIME PERMISSION IN ANDROID

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 101;

public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == yourBtn.getId()) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.storageWork();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, PERMISSION_REQ_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQ_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.storageWork();
        }
    }
}

public void storageWork(){
}
```

OnClick method is to check runtime permission

and if Permission is restricted then it request permission

Answer (score 0):

Just this will do:

```
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 0);
        }
```