# When to request permission at runtime for Android Marshmallow 6.0?

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I am testing my app on `Marshmallow 6.0` and it's getting force closed for the `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, even if it is defined in the Manifest already. Somewhere I have read that if I request permission at runtime then it would not force close your application. I have read [this android document](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html) also, which is for requesting runtime permission.

So, I came to know that we can request a permission like below which is mentioned in the android document.

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

The above code has a callback method `onRequestPermissionsResult` which gets the result.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

     }
}
```

My question is where to exactly request the permission to user? Should we use the requesting permission at start of the app or should we do it as when the permission is required?

Comment: Have a look at this video: https://youtu.be/iZqDdvhTZj0 - There are some best practices explained.

Comment: do it as when the permission is required. Also, verify the permission l-o-c in manifest for M; `<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: So requesting the permission when needed is the best practice.

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Comment: also see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41978011/3496570

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android marshmallow request permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, request needed permissions it as soon as you need them. This way you can inform the user why you need the permission and handle permission denies much easier.

Think of scenarios where the user revokes the permission while your app runs: If you request it at startup and never check it later this could lead to unexpected behaviour or exceptions.

Comment: So your saying I have to request permission  when we needed not at start up.

Comment: Yes. You don't know if the user revokes the permission during the runtime of you app.

Answer (score 7):

This is worked for me !!!
In Your Splash Activity of your application do the following,

1) Declare an int variable for request code,

> `private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 2;`

2) Declare a string array with the number of permissions you need,

```
 String[] mPermission = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
 Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
```

3) Next Check the condition for runtime permission on your onCreate method,

```
try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission[0])
                    != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission[1])
                            != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission[2])
                            != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission[3])
                            != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        mPermission, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);

              // If any permission aboe not allowed by user, this condition will execute every tim, else your else part will work
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

4) Now Declare onRequestPermissionsResult method to check the request code,

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.e("Req Code", "" + requestCode);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length == 4 &&
                    grantResults[0] == MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    grantResults[1] == MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    grantResults[2] == MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    grantResults[3] == MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

               // Success Stuff here

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Didn't get your code your saying do your stuff here at two places. There should be only one place to do my stuff not at two and how `onRequestPermissionsResult` would be called???

Comment: Sorry for that, just do the code in onRequestPermissionResult and then tell me ur result

Answer (score 4):

**Do like this**

```
private static final int  REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 111;
```

In your onCreate

```
boolean hasPermissionLocation = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermissionLocation) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ThisActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
```

then check result

```
   @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode)
    {

        case REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(ThisActivity.this, "Permission granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //reload my activity with permission granted
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());

            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(ThisActivity.this, "The app was not allowed to get your location. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, there is no one correct answer to your question. I strongly suggest you to look at this official [permissions patterns page](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/permissions.html).

Couple of things suggested by Google :

> "Your permissions strategy depends on the clarity and importance of the permission type you are requesting. These patterns offer different ways of introducing permissions to the user."
>
> "Critical permissions should be requested up-front. Secondary permissions may be requested in-context."
>
> "Permissions that are less clear should provide education about what the permission involves, whether done up-front or in context."

[This illustration](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3QXkxaEJ4OTM3X0E/patterns_permissions_patterns0.png) might give you better understanding.

Maybe the most crucial thing here is that whether you ask the permission up-front or in the context, you should always keep in mind that these permissions can be revoked anytime by the user (e.g. your app is still running, in background).

You should make sure that your app doesn't crash just because you asked the permission on the very beginning of the app and assumed that user didn't change his/her preference about that permission.

Comment: this is my opinion too, there is no correct awnser for this question, the guys from ux should decide this depending on the product

Answer (score 1):

For requesting runtime permission i use [GitHub Library](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission)

Add library in `Build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
     compile 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:1.0.3'
}
```

Create Activity and add `PermissionListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {
            Toast.makeText(RationaleDenyActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Camera Intent and access Location logic here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
            Toast.makeText(RationaleDenyActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };


    new TedPermission(this)
            .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
            .setRationaleTitle(R.string.rationale_title)
            .setRationaleMessage(R.string.rationale_message) // "we need permission for access camera and find your location"
            .setDeniedTitle("Permission denied")
            .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
            .setGotoSettingButtonText("Settings")
            .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .check();
   }
}
```

### string.xml

```
<resources>

    <string name="rationale_title">Permission required</string>
    <string name="rationale_message">we need permission for read <b>camera</b> and find your <b>location</b></string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Android Easy Runtime Permissions with Dexter:
    1. Dexter Permissions Library

    To get started with Dexter, add the dependency in your build.gradle

    dependencies {
        // Dexter runtime permissions
        implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    }

    1.1 Requesting Single Permission
    To request a single permission, you can use withPermission() method by passing the required permission. You also need a PermissionListener callback to receive the state of the permission.

    > onPermissionGranted() will be called once the permission is granted.

    > onPermissionDenied() will be called when the permission is denied. Here you can check whether the permission is permanently denied by using response.isPermanentlyDenied() condition.

    The below code requests CAMERA permission.

Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        // permission is granted, open the camera
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        // check for permanent denial of permission
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // navigate user to app settings
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();

1.2 Requesting Multiple Permissions
To request multiple permissions at the same time, you can use withPermissions() method. Below code requests STORAGE and LOCATION permissions.

Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            // do you work now
                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // permission is denied permenantly, navigate user to app settings
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
```

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation and HowTo can be found here:

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

I wrote this code to check and request the permissions at runtime in a BaseActivity.class which is parent of every other Activity.class I implemented:

```
public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 42;
public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 43;

//Marshmallow Permission Model
public boolean requestPermission(String permission /* Manifest.permission...*/) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Utils.hasMarshmallow())
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{permission}, PERMISSION_REQUEST
            );
        else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{permission},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean requestPermission(String... permissions) {
    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String perm : permissions) {
        addPermission(permissionsList, perm);
    }

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (Utils.hasMarshmallow())
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}


private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        // Check for Rationale Option
        if (Utils.hasMarshmallow())
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST:
        case MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Simply example call:

```
activity.requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Return result will let you know if the permission is already granted or not.

Answer (score 0):

**calling this function we can allow user to open dialog for asking permission to allow camera and record Audio.**

```
    if ( ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ||
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (this,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) ) {
        Toast.makeText (this,
                R.string.permissions_needed,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions (
                this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                CAMERA_MIC_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/permissions.html 
This link will give you different type of scenario where permissions can be asked. Choose accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I like short code. I use [**RxPermission**](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) for permissions.

[**RxPermission**](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) is best library, which makes permission code unexpected just 1 line.

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);
rxPermissions
.request(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
         Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) // ask single or multiple permission once
.subscribe(granted -> {
    if (granted) {
       // All requested permissions are granted
    } else {
       // At least one permission is denied
    }
});
```

add in your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
}
```

**Isn't this easy?**

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ||
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (this,
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) ) {
            Toast.makeText (this,
                    R.string.permissions_needed,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions (
                    this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    CAMERA_MIC_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
```

Comment: You are lacking comments to your code, what are you doing differently in your answer? and your previous answer?