# AppCompatActivity and Marshmallow Permissions

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

My app uses "dangerous" permissions such as `READ_CONTACTS`, among others.  All the examples I have seen to support this new model use classes derived from `AppCompatActivity`. Do I really have to change my activities that subclass Activity to now subclass `AppCompatActivity`? Is there an alternative way of doing this while still using activities?  When I make that change my app crashes.

Comment: Can you post your error here.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission/34722591#34722591 I Explain simple.....

Comment: I explain Simple at Below Link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission/34722591#34722591

Comment: you can use google library for permission. I have explained here.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41893773/1429832

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I really have to change my activities that subclass Activity to now subclass AppCompatActivity?

No.

> Is there an alternative way of doing this while still using activities?

It's the same way. There is nothing in `AppCompatActivity` that has anything to do with runtime permissions. Whether you are inheriting from `Activity`, `AppCompatActivity`, or `PhilodendronActivity`, you:

- Call `checkSelfPermission()` (on your `Context` or the `static` edition on `ContextCompat`) to see if you hold the permission
- Call `requestPermissions()` (on your `Activity` or the `static` edition on `ActivityCompat`) to request the permissions from the user
- Implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on your `Activity` to get the result of the `requestPermissions()` call

So, for example, none of these sample apps use `AppCompatActivity`:

- An [app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/PermissionMonger) just there to explore runtime permissions
- The [results](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/tutorial/finish/RuntimePermTutorial) of completing a hands-on tutorial to experiment with adding runtime permissions
- [Two apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location) that show requesting runtime permissions as part of setting up Play Services' fused location provider
- An [app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2) that sets up runtime permissions for Maps V2 use

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look shortly.  Is it best to ask for all permissions at once, or one at a time, as dictated by user action?  Read contacts is required at the beginning but write external storage may never be required if user doesn't take an action that requires it?

Comment: @PhilO: Usually, you wait on requesting the permission until the user action, so you ask for as few permissions as possible. If the permission might not make sense to the user in the context of the user action, and you think that having some sort of "welcome" onboarding activity and asking for the permission up front might smooth things for the user, that's reasonable.