# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions doesn't show dialog

Tags: java, android

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

And in PreActivity.java

```
if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(preActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(preActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
        setDisplay();

    } else {
        // show dialog here
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(preActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);

    }
} else {
    ～～～～～
}
```

After requestPermissions() is called, onRequestPermissionsResult is called without showing confirmation dialog box.

Does anyone know what the problem is, or how to show this dialog?

Thank you.

Comment: Does that happen even if you uninstall the app and installed from scratch?

Comment: are you sure that you already have NOT granted permission to your app?

Comment: Yes that happens. I have tried to re-install many times but the problem didn't solve...

Comment: Does `setDisplay()` contains anything that calls `requestPermissions()`? It could be that the permission may have been denied.

Comment: Surely I don't grant permission.

Comment: Try debugging with breakpoints and see.

Comment: There is not anything that calls requestPermissions().
setDisplay() is not called at all now.

Comment: Did you mean to type [<uses-permission-sdk-23>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html)? The dialog also will not be shown if it was shown before and the user denied it and checked never to show it again.

Comment: Use `uses-permission-sdk-23` instead `uses-permission-sdk-m` as it's deprecated and do a complete re-installation of the application do not updgrade. How about the version of phone your using ?

Comment: Give a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission/33666161#33666161

Comment: Thank you Anoop M. I'll try this.
The version of my phone is 5.0.2, but I usually use emulators for the test and these versions are between 4.2.2 and 6.0.0.

Comment: I tried to use sdk-23, but confirmation dialog didn't show yet. sorry...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you have already granted the required permission to your app.

To test from scratch first uninstall your app and then try again. This way all of the previously granted permissions will be revoked.

Comment: Thank you for answering, SMR.
But sorry, the problem doesn't solve.
I call this at the starting of my app, and if I call a method using GPS at the next, SecurityException occurs and my app terminates forcibly.