# how to guide user to open permission in system setting for my app

Tags: android, permissions, system, setting

all

I have a question about android 6 permission. If user deny to grant permission, user cannot use some function in my app. How can i use code to guide user to app permission setting in system setting app, so that user can open this permission. I don't find related method. Can you help me about this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Marshmallow, you should request for the permissions.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33666161/5577853

```
     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("", "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("", " permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                    } else {
                            Log.d("", "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                            //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
    // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                            //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                                showDialogOK("This app needs something something, please grant permissions",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                switch (which) {
                                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                        checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                        break;
                                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                        // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please go to settings and enable permissions.", 2000).show();
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                            //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                                   //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
    //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    
    private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
       
        int permissionWriteExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int permissionCallPhone = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
       
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();
       
        if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
       
        }
        if (permissionCallPhone != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you may request again for the permissions whereever it needed.

Comment: if user deny it and select never ask, i cannot get permission dialog at all. so i want to guide user to setting and open it by himself. I think it is better to only notify user that he don't have permission.

Comment: @ anurag shrivastava, thanks your help very much.i just check a method to guide user to app setting:                            Intent myIntent = new Intent();                            myIntent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);  Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", context.getPackageName(), null);   myIntent.setData(uri);                            startActivity(myIntent); But it cannot go to permission page of this app. That is not so good for me by now.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code.

```
 public static void mOpenActivity(Context context) {
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }
    final Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_    SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" +     context.getPackageName()));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
context.startActivity(i);
}
```