# missing permissions required by BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled.BLUETOOTH

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-permissions

I add bluetooth to my app but am running into the following problem. When I do the code:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device doesnt Support Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);
}
```

The error is on the following line:

```
if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
```

Error:

> Missing permissions required by BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled :android.permissions.BLUETOOTH

I added the following permissions to the android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:label="BLUETOOTH" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

but am still getting the same issue. Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: can you provide the code of your Activty/Fragment.

Comment: Are you testing with Android 6.0 or above? You need to request permission at the run time. Having permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` is not enough. Read here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html  See a simple example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @th3pat3l could you tell me specifically how to do run time permissions for bluetooth?

Comment: @ComputerGeek101 check out my answer. It should give you an idea on what you have to do in Android M and above

Comment: Did you copy and paste that error message exactly?

Comment: When I type @RequiredApi it gives me an error. Do you know why? It says cannot resolve symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You only need `<uses-permission>` tag since you are using a permission. You don't need `<permissions>` tag since this is not your custom permission.
2. Maybe you have placed `<uses-permission>` tag in the wrong element in manifest, but I cannot say anything else with the information you provided
3. Since your bluetoothAdapter can be null, either add to second IF null pointer check, or add a RETURN in first IF
4. It is also nice to have `<uses-feature>` tag

Comment: thanks, I accidentally put my permissions in the application tags.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a button and then you click on it, Bluetooth needs to turn on. Here's a quick example how you would do it for Android 6.0 and above.

First, declare this variable in your `Activity`/`Fragment`:

```
public static final int PERMISSION_ASK = 1001;
```

Now, let's say this buttons is going to enable the bluetooth.
`setOnClickListener`:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(isBluetoothPermissionGranted()) {
                // app already has required permissions
                // do some task here
            } else {
                // app does not have permission yet.
                // ask for permissions
                askForBluetoothPermissions();
            }
        } else {
            // Android version below 6.0, no need to check or ask for permission
            // do some task here
        }
    }
});
```

Checking if application already has the required permission:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean isBluetoothPermissionGranted() {
    boolean granted = false;
    int bluetoothGranted = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);
    int bluetoothAdminGranted = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN);

    if(bluetoothGranted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            bluetoothAdminGranted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        granted = true;
    }

    return granted;
}
```

If required permission is not granted, here's how you would ask for it:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void askForBluetoothPermissions() {
    String[] permissions = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
    };
    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_ASK);
}
```

And finally, here's how you would confirm if the user granted you the permission(s) or not:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_ASK:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // all requested permissions were granted
                // perform your task here
            } else {
                // permissions not granted
                // DO NOT PERFORM THE TASK, it will fail/crash
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Google's new motto: "Turning one line of code into a hundred, since 2008."

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I see what you mean but look at it this way, at least the option is there. iOS doesn't even allow non-system application to turn on WiFi or simple features like that. Android is used on so many different systems at so many different version levels. Of course, more work will be required. iOS is built for one phone. Not many options there

Comment: I'm comparing this to earlier versions of Android, not iOS.  Google is always looking for ways to make simple things harder, and runtime permissions were a totally uncalled-for misfeature.  I'm simply not targeting 6+ until Google comes to its senses.

Comment: Idk. I personally wouldn't called it ubcalled-for misfeature. The feature is the ability to grant and deny permission from the user perspective. Not the fact that it makes developer life easy/hard

Comment: My target android version is lollipop, so when I tried this it did not work

Answer (score 1):

For Android 6.0 and above you must add the following to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:label="BLUETOOTH" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```