# FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/JsonParseTutorialCache: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm using GridView to load json data holding images. When I built project it happened some exceptions

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

FileCache class:

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context) {
    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "JsonParseTutorialCache");
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url) throws IOException {
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    f.createNewFile();
    return f;
}

public void clear() {
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    if (files == null)
        return;
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
 }
```

}

Logcat:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
W/System.err:     at    com.totoroads.android.app.FileCache.getFile(FileCache.java:33) 
W/System.err:     at com.totoroads.android.app.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:64)
W/System.err:     at com.totoroads.android.app.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:29)
W/System.err:     at com.totoroads.android.app.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:155)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
W/System.err:   ... 9 more
```

I want to download, read and display images on GridView, How to fix those exceptions?

Comment: "/storage/emulated/0/JsonParseTutorialCache/-1068682472" I don't think this is a valid file path for an image. You should check if you're fetching file name correctly.

Comment: I get images by parameter is: TAG_ICONNAME="image"(from json)

Comment: Please post a sample json response too.

Comment: @TheAbsurd: I have updated more FileCache class and JSON, please review it above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in FileCache.java is

```
public File getFile(String url) {
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;
}
```

A new file object has been created, but the file may not exist. So, replace the above code with

```
public File getFile(String url) {
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    f.createNewFile();
    return f;
}
```

Hope, it helps.

Edit : As you're running your code on >= Android 6.0, you gotta request for permission to access External Storage at runtime. Adding those in AndroidManifest.xml isn't enough. You can use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission) on how to do it.

Comment: @TheAburd: I have updated as your code, it's seem same error, you can see Logcat

Comment: Are you running this code in Marshmallow or higher?

Comment: I haven't clear your question, but my code is running on development environment (android studio)

Comment: Marshmallow: Nexus 5x API 23 (Android 6, API 23)

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it was:

If targeting Android 10 (API level 29) or higher, set the value of `requestLegacyExternalStorage` to `true` in your app's `AndroidManifest` file.

```
<manifest ... >
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
```

Comment: Awesome.. this was indeed the issue in my case, where despite WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime, i was not able to create the directory.

Comment: This was the case for me as well. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: FYI, the answer above is a short way to resolve the problem. But as far as you should migrate your data from local to the scope store before upgrade to android 11. you can check here to know how can migrate: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate-legacy-storage

Answer (score 1):

You can use Picasso library for showing images in grid view.
it is provide one line code for load image.
Use Library function for load images--

Picasso.with(context).load("**YOURIMAGE**").into(imageView);

You can also resize images according to your requirement.
and it is also manage  internally cache mechanism

Refer Link for more info -
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I will try and back to you

Comment: Thank you for your advice about picasso, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also save yourself the `f.createNewFile` and use `File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir)`

So your method now becomes

```
public File getFile(String url) {
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);

    return File.createTempFile(filename, ".jpg", cacheDir);
}
```