# How to make the app check if the permission is granted or not (6,x+) Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have an SMS App where now in 6.0 the user have to allow the app to send SMS.
Right now i have this code which i got from [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it).

```js
 int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS=0;
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
```

But when i deny acess (if the user accidently hit the button) everythings will pretty much make the app crash (Cause sms buttons wont work). So when the user starts/reboot the app after the user have denied access i would like the app to ask again. Right now when i tried on my emulator no dialog would come up again so i had to go to settings/app and set permission. Or uninstall and install again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android marshmallow request permission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is asking the user for permission, but not checking if the permissions were actually granted. You can do this by implementing the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method in the activity from which you request the permissions.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722591/3872500 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

An example using a different permission from a working app with comments where you need to make your changes:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

        //This is where you need to ask again if they want to allow the permission,
        //you should show a dialog here to ask if they're sure
        //and explain why you need the permission.
        requestDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.device_setup_location_permission_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.device_setup_location_permission_message))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //They clicked yes, they want to enable the permission,
                        //so let's show them the dialog again.
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DeviceSetupActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                REQUEST_LOCATION_RESPONSE);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.later), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //This means they don't want to grant the permission, 
                        //you should exit the app here, perhaps share another dialog saying that in
                        //order to use the app, the permission must be granted.
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_LOCATION_RESPONSE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION_RESPONSE){
        if(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)){
            startScan();
        }else{
            //exit the activity
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED==checkSelfPermission(perm));
    }
    return true;
}
```