# Permissions don't work and are not asked when i install the program

Tags: android, permissions

We wrote all permission codes between suitable tags. But when i install the program there is no ask about permissions.
Where is my fault?

this my manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.berker.notkayit">

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="21"
android:targetSdkVersion="24" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android marshmallow request permission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)

Answer (score 0):

Writing permissions in Manifest file won't ask permissions on runtime. In order to show permissions, you need to write code in your application instances. Refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

are u testing the app in marshmallow or above device means it won't ask for permission during installation but it will permission during run time have u added the runtime permission codes

Answer (score 0):

It dependences on your devices, if you device Android version is below 6.0, then you way is ok, however, if you device version is 6.0 and above then you need add runtime permission, check this link https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions