# Android SQLite asset copying error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to read and write to a SQLite database in assets using Android but I don't
know why I get an error. I will post every thing below:

First of all, my DatabaseHelper.java file:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by Koorosh on 1/6/2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    String DB_PATH = null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "mydatabase";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 10);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_PATH = myContext.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/" + "databases/";
        Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
    }


    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }


}
```

I have also added these two in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here I call my db helper class in the Main Activity:

```
        DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }
```

This is the database file:

https://ufile.io/4e23c

**Note**

1. I should mention that in DB_NAME I tried both "mydatabase.db" and "mydatabase" but again it did not work.
2. I am programming on a phone that its locale is Persian (Farsi). Is this my problem? (Because I added english metadata in database)

This is my error log:

```
01-06 19:48:29.847 26854-26854/com.example.koorosh.doctor E/Path 1: /data/user/0/com.example.koorosh.doctor/files/databases/
01-06 19:48:29.847 26854-26854/com.example.koorosh.doctor E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 32578 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
01-06 19:48:29.847 26854-26854/com.example.koorosh.doctor E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:32578: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.example.koorosh.doctor/files/databases/mydatabase.db) - 
01-06 19:48:29.849 26854-26854/com.example.koorosh.doctor E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.example.koorosh.doctor/files/databases/mydatabase.db'.
                                                                            android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:208)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:192)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:464)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:186)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:916)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:893)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:796)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:771)
                                                                                at com.example.koorosh.doctor.DatabaseHelper.checkDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:52)
                                                                                at com.example.koorosh.doctor.DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:36)
                                                                                at com.example.koorosh.doctor.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
01-06 19:48:29.853 26854-26854/com.example.koorosh.doctor D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-06 19:48:29.854 26854-26854/com.example.koorosh.doctor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.koorosh.doctor, PID: 26854
                                                                            java.lang.Error: Error copying database
                                                                                at com.example.koorosh.doctor.DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:43)
                                                                                at com.example.koorosh.doctor.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
01-06 19:48:35.803 26854-26854/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26854 SIG: 9
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are using Marshmallow or above version phones you need Android permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Check [Normal and Dangerous Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous)

Comment: I have mentioned that I have already added them into my manifest

Comment: Nope, you also need to ask permission in Java code. Check the above link. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33666071/5180017) StackOverflow thread.

Comment: no change has happened :(