# How to request runtime permissions in Android on app launch?

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

Whenever I start my app before granting permissions, it stops and asks for permissions. It works fine the second time it's launched.

Comment: Look: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: check permission before using the resources

Answer (score -1):

Follow this links :

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Runtime_Permission_Requests_in_Android_6.0
[Android marshmallow request permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html