# Java Android requestPermissions after click button

Tags: java, android

This is how I request permissions :

```
  private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int phoneStatePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (cameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }

        if (phoneStatePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I call this method after click button :

```
@OnClick(R.id.email_sign_in_button)
void loginButton() {
    if(checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
        attemptLogin();
    }
}
```

But when a user confirm all permissions have to click one more time button. What I have to do that user do not click a button ?

Comment: have a look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission/43322136#43322136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the activity's `onRequestPermissionsResult` method, it will be called when the user accepts/rejects permissions. You can find more details [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Here is an example specific to your case:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS && grantResults.length == listPermissionsNeeded.size()){
        boolean allGranted = true;
        for(int grantedResult : grantedResults){
            if(grantedResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                allGranted = false;
            }
        }
        if(allGranted){
            attemptLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the onRequestPermissionsResult in your Activity/Fragment.

As statet in the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request), you can implement this to check if the user has granted the requested permissions:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
>              // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>             if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>                 // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                 // contacts-related task you need to do.
>
>             } else {
>
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'case' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     }
> }
> ```

Remember to alter the switch/case according to your needs. If the user has granted all permissions, just call *attemptLogin()* once again.

Answer (score 0):

Use RxPermissions: No need to again click on button after allow permissions

gradle

```
compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.7.0@aar'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
```

code

```
 RxPermissions.getInstance(this)
                        .request(REQUEST_PERMISSIONS)
                        .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(Boolean granted) {
                                if (granted) {
                                    attemptLogin();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```