# Android: unable to read a file using bufferedReader whereas cat command run in adb shell works fine

Tags: java, android, shell, bufferedreader, file-permissions

I am trying to read a system file using bufferedReader in Android API=23 but it gives the following error: **open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**.

The file is read only. On the other hand, 'cat' command run in adb shell just works fine.

Also, **File.exists() returns true** for my file whereas **File.canRead() returns false**.
**Is it something related to the administrative/root access?
Does adb shell give you root access to system?**

P.S.:I  have granted Read/Write permissions to the app (**as per API 23**)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android marshmallow request permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)

Comment: Can you give the file's path here?

Comment: post ur manifest

Comment: No. I have taken that into account. I can read other files with ease!!

Comment: You should use Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for requestPermissions in API = 23

Comment: For API 23+ you need to request the read/write permissions even if they are already in your manifest.

Comment: Please log your file's path and update on question.

Comment: @AvinashRoy I have included the  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in my manifest just before the application tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem was very much unique to my case. The file was a system file and my app was not given the Permission to read it. It was rectified after I **signed my app** as a **system app**.

Probable other solution might be if the app will have root permissions to read such file.

Thanks everyone for  your  suggestions and answers!!

Answer (score 0):

Android added new permission model for Android 6.0 (Marshmallow).

http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal

So you have to check Runtime Permission :

What Are Runtime Permissions?

With Android 6.0 Marshmallow, Google introduced a new permission model that allows users to better understand why an application may be requesting specific permissions. Rather than the user blindly accepting all permissions at install time, the user is now prompted to accept permissions as they become necessary during application use.

When to Implement the New Model?

it doesn’t require full support until you choose to target version 23 in your application. If you are targeting version 22 or below, your application will request all permissions at install time just as it would on any device running an OS below Marshmallow.

This information is taken from here :

Please check How to implement from this link :

http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal

Comment: I have added runtime permission check and have granted the read/write permissions during runtime. That is not the issue. It is specifically this file.

Comment: I checked the permissions for this file (using adb shell) and got "read only". Adb shell command -cat works fine for this file. Is it because of root access granted during the adb shell?

Comment: where is that file located??

Comment: Are you running on a emulator or a physical device? Does the /sdcard path exist?

Comment: The file is a system file. And i am running it on a physical device.

Comment: my device is not rooted. Could that be the issue for reading the file?

Comment: I guess not an issue

Comment: You cannot access that app's files on internal storage. Your permissions are for external storage.

Comment: It is not the problem. you can still read a file in internal storage.

Comment: @Avinash Yeah that may be an issue. I will check on that. But for some reason other system files are readable with these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If your file exists but can not read, please make sure the followings:
- Permission. Because you can read other files as you said, it may not a problem.
- It is **not folder**. check it by `file.isDirectory()`.
- **Check your file path**. For example, it should not start like that: `file:/...`  or `/home/storage//th` (when you mistakenly append with two dashes).

Comment: it is not a folder. Since cat FILEPATH returns me the desired output.

Comment: Another common issue as I mentioned above is your file path.

Comment: Check them by log two properties: 
- file.isDirectory()  
- file.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: Output of log properties: isDirectory: false; getAbsolutePath: *returns correct path*; exists(): true; canRead(): false. Thought the permissions for the file is readonly!!

Comment: Please check the final condition. - file path, and update your question with your codes.