# Why app crashes when i set image to ImageView and run it on android 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am new to Android. I want to know why my app crashes on Android 7.1.1 while setting the image to imageView using explicit intent, as it totally runs fine on other versions of Android. I have tried to understand and solve the issue but unable to do.

Can anyone please help me to understand why this is happening and what's the reason behind this?

Thanks.

This is what it showing :

```
eAnimators on 0x97c5ee80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9affd880
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.himanshu.imageviewintent, PID: 5049
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/41 }} to activity {com.example.himanshu.imageviewintent/com.example.himanshu.imageviewintent.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/41 from pid=5049, uid=10073 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/41 from pid=5049, uid=10073 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
                      at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:692)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1147)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:984)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:704)
                      at com.example.himanshu.imageviewintent.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:44)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

And this is my code :

**Java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final static int ImageIntentRequest = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void setImage(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        File imageViewPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String path =  imageViewPath.getPath();
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path),"image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,ImageIntentRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == ImageIntentRequest) {

            InputStream stream;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            try {
             stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"There is no File Present",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XML :**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.himanshu.imageviewintent.MainActivity"
>

<Button
    android:text="@string/set_image_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_set_image"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="setImage"
    />

<ImageView
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_set_image"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**I found an easy fix for this :**

I just replaced,

```
Intent.ACTION_PICK by -

Intent intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

and now the app runs totally fine on old and latest releases of Android.

But still have doubts:

Why ACTION_PICK works on old versions of Android but not on new Releases?
Why ACTION_GET_CONTENT works on all releases?

I will be thankful if someone clarify this?

Comment: Make sure about the runtime permissions...

Comment: Did you analyze the Crash Report in **Logcat**?

Comment: Please post your crashlog

Comment: @Ronak yes, I make sure about them.

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: You need to request permissions at run time, for newer devices (6.0 and above). They are not given on installation like they used to be. [read more here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Did you declared permission in your manifest file and also for android 6.0 & above

Comment: you haven't used runtime permission. It will crash for 6.0+

Comment: please show your code..where you grant run time permission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android marshmallow request permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)

Comment: in this code where is run time permission..? please follow this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request

Comment: @Dileep Patel I thought about the uses permission in manifest file.
I don't know about the run time permission
Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @HimanshuVerma its ok NP..

Comment: I found an easy fix for this, please have a look at the edited version of the question and clarify my doubts.
 I replaced ACTION_PICK  by  ACTION_GET_CONTENT and now it works fine on all releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#sharing-files) on the changes introduced in Android Nougat, you'll find this -

> For apps targeting Android 7.0, the Android framework enforces the
>   StrictMode API policy that prohibits exposing file:// URIs outside
>   your app. If an intent containing a file URI leaves your app, the app
>   fails with a FileUriExposedException exception.
>
> To share files between applications, you should send a content:// URI
>   and grant a temporary access permission on the URI. The easiest way to
>   grant this permission is by using the FileProvider class.

Here, your intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    File imageViewPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String path =  imageViewPath.getPath();
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path),"image/*");
```

is leaving your app to open the Gallery/Camera to pick an image, which results into a crash, as it does not follow Android Nougat Protocol.

To resolve your problem, change the targetApi in your gradle file to 23 (marshmallow) down from 24/25/26 (whichever you may be having as of now).

Or, you can read more on [File Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) and do it in a way that does not violate StrictMode policy.

In case you are short on time, you can use [EasyImage](https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage) library to solve your purpose.

Comment: I just replaced ACTION_PICK by ACTION_GET_CONTENT and it solved my problem but I don't know why? Please clarify this.

Comment: Take a look at the description given in the document [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT).

"Allow the user to select a particular kind of data and return it. This is different than ACTION_PICK in that here we just say what kind of data is desired, not a URI of existing data from which the user can pick."

Comment: Thanks, Kunal Chawla for the clarification. I understand the difference now.

Comment: @HimanshuVerma you're most welcome. Glad I could help. Thanks for accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take runtime permission from the user to read external storage.

You can use following code for asking permission from user.

Hope it will help you.

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestStoragePermission();
    } else { 
        loadImageInImageview();
    }


    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 1000);
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            if (grantResults.length != 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                loadImageInImageview();
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Allow permission.")
                        .setMessage("Please....")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have either not added Storage permissions to the manifest or you do not ask the user to accept them before using them.

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

You can ask user for permission using this function

```
    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }

}
```