# Unfortunately app Stopped - While running in real device but working well in emulator

Tags: android

My Android App is running successfully in android studio emulator, but after installing the same apk file in my mobile it is installing and it is shows the following error

> Unfortunately app stopped

while I try to open it.
how to fix? My android version is 6.0(both emulator and mobile).

Comment: show us your log. of the error...

Comment: Update error message from your log. So we can understand the issue better .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the permissions of your application. Since version 6 of Android, you must request the permissions on demand.

Look at this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722591/3665983