# How to make a phone call using Image view?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

When I am clicking on Image its not responding. But when i add onClick() in XML so it gets to crash. I am having multiple images to do same help me with it.

XML file

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cto"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fb"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fb"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fb"
            android:src="@drawable/callto" />
```

Java File

```
    public class Content_main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView call;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_main);

        call = findViewById(R.id.cto);

        call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 9871275493"));
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Content_main.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

> Its Error when I add onClick value & if I am not adding it's not responding

```
03-29 17:24:57.188 4158-4158/com.flavourbasket.flavourbasket E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.flavourbasket.flavourbasket, PID: 4158
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'cto'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Your **`error`** says something else but your code says something else, !! **According to the error , you havent used any AppcompatImageView in your code**

Comment: @SantanuSur this is not true. onClick is a method of the View class (superclass of ImageView) and the reason is the wrong xml attribute...

Comment: `on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'cto'` i still dint get this :- @appersiano can you explain ? He is using `imageView` not `AppCompatImageView` ..both are completely different widgets !!

Comment: @santanu Sir please, Stop this And tell me the Solution. Tomorrow is the deadLine.

Comment: @SantanuSur a copy and paste mistake by the user I think

Comment: @VivekPathak first run your project and paste the latest codes and latest errors !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this You just forgot **`@Override`**

```
  call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 9871275493"));
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Content_main.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT**

also remove **`android:onClick="onClick"`** from your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cto"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fb"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fb"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fb"
    android:src="@drawable/callto" />
```

Comment: It's exact same

Comment: Then the image is not responding it seems static only

Comment: @VivekPathak didn't get u

Comment: When we click on any Button if it doesn't have any connectivity so it's not working ---- As that image is shown to me.

Comment: use @Override is a good practise but is not the reason of the crash VivekPathak

Comment: @appersiano okay sir

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your xml to solve the crash

```
 android:onClick="onClick"
```

next remember to, ask for runtime permission with `requestPermission` method (example)

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
```

Comment: then when I am clicking on image Its not responding

Comment: is the permission granted?

Comment: Yes, At the top of the application tag

Comment: you have also to ask runtime permissions...not only in the declare it in the manifest check this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I see that you are only checking for permission and not use  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions method so I think that your code return

Comment: I have put the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions in else and MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE shows me an error how to solve it ?

Comment: Because is not declared anywhere...read the link of the documentation please and next I'll see that I am right

Comment: I have put the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions in else and MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE shows me an error how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Is either you add the onclick method from xml, or set the listener using

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {}
        }
```

Comment: Ok I have removed the onClick, That's still same- And image-view is not responding

Comment: you need to grant runtime permission to access phone call

Comment: goto settings -> apps -> open your application -> goto permissions -> click phone and grant the permission @VivekPathak

Comment: It that In phone Or android studio or in emulator ?

Comment: the device you are testing on

Comment: if you want to do it programmatically check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission

Comment: are you sure you don't have duplicate view ids

Comment: Yes, If it was then my app has to get crash and just because of confusion

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the casting. you are not casting imageview. try casting it