# Permission denied reading from gallery Android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am working on Android app which gets image from gallery and displays it ... but it is displaying blank screen and the error is:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage...jpeg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

code:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

and I've added in AndroidManifest:

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: Do you requestThePermission to the user

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission

Comment: Thanks very much @crammeur

Comment: That an pleasure.