# What is grant results which is passed when onrequest permission granted () is created

Tags: java, android, permissions

Can anyone explain why `onRequestPermisionRequest` is created and what is the use of grant results which is passed as argument in Java for Android?

Comment: Chcek this answer->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission

Comment: Thanks understood it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method, `onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)`, you are passing a `String` array of permissions that are needed and when the user is asked for all the permissions, the control comes back to this function, where the `int[]` array `grantResults` contains the status of permissions corresponsding to the string array passed. The `grantPermissions` array will contain only `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED` corresponding to the string array of permissions.