# How does file system access differ between KitKat 4.2 and Nougat 7.1.1?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-7.1-nougat, filesystem-access

I have an app HTMLSpyII that I developed a few years ago when I was an absolute beginner at Android programming. Anyway here it is a few years later, I have been away from programming through this time, it has been running on my Samsung S4 mini KitKat 4.4.2, but it will not run on my Samsung Tab E Nougat 7.1.1. I am certain that I am missing something simple.

The program is trying to create a directory /HTMLSpyII/Jsoup in the Downloads directory of the device. It outputs this two-line runTimeAlert from the last line of the following code snippet...
Unable to create path
/storage/emulated/0/Download/HTMLSpyII/Jsoup

Here is the code snippet, which is part of onCreate...

```
    private File root;
    private String urlString, tokenString;
    private EditText url, token;
    ...
 root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/HTMLSpyII/Jsoup");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            urlString = extras.getString("urlKey");
            url.setText(urlString);
            tokenString = extras.getString("tokenKey");
            token.setText(tokenString);
            if (getIntent().hasExtra("redirectsKey"))
                followRedirects = extras.getBoolean("redirectsKey");
            else
                followRedirects = true;
            if (getIntent().hasExtra("rootKey"))
                root = new File (extras.getString("rootKey"));
        }
        if (!root.exists()) root.mkdirs();
        if (!root.isDirectory())
            runTimeAlert("Unable to create path\n" + root.toString())
```

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the answer to my question involves checking permissions at run time. This was new to me. 
 The answer is provided by Tarun, in this StackOverflow post...
[Android marshmallow request permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)
Tarun's answer is quite far down so easiest to find it by searching the post for the name Tarun; and found here also...
http://revisitingandroid.blogspot.com/2017/01/how-to-check-and-request-for-run-time.html