# Permission not asked

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I'd like to know why my permission are not asked when I'm launching my app, here's my manifest permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

And when I go through the param of my phone, I only have the "position" permission (and it's disabled).

Comment: Is your device and target sdk at least 26? Because Marshmallow introduced Runtime Permissions.

Comment: I have an Xperia XA1 Ultra (Android 8.0) and the SDK 28 (I see that in my gradle, right ?)

Answer (score 2):

If by permission not asked you mean that the user isn't being prompted to allow internet permission then that is normal. Internet is in the normal permissions list so it is auto granted. For more information about normal permissions take a look at: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html

Also, adding permissions is a two step process; once you have declared the permission you need in your manifest, you will also have to do some setup in your java file. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Additionally, if you are looking for easier ways to deal with permissions then there are libraries out there for that too such as RxPermissions: https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Thanks for the infos, i'll check asap.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask for a Runtime Permission
Please see the documentation:
[Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting SDK 26+, then you need to check for permissions in code like this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// Permission is not granted
// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
} else {
    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
} else {
// Permission has already been granted - or running on old Android
}
```

It is described in [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Answer (score 0):

for marshmallow(API 23) and above you should get permission for location, phone states and other [dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous-permission-prompt) not only in your manifest but in your code (Run Time Permission).for other permissions, manifest is enough.

see [this video](https://youtu.be/C8lUdPVSzDk)
also you can find your solution  in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)