# How to convert String to Uri which is taken from sqlite and set it in ImageView?

Tags: java, android, image, sqlite, uri

I was saving image Uri to SQLite as String which I picked from gallery and it was set as image to my ImageView. But from 2nd activity I'm taking the Image(Uri) as String and converting to Uri and setting to ImageView.

When I run the 2nd activity it is giving an error like

```
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/06.jpg
```

The code is like.

```
String valueImage;

imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(valueImage));
```

Do I need to convert in another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/beraybentesen/glide-xamarin-android). It's very easy and takes only one line.

```
String valueImage; // Get url fro SQLite

Glide
     .With(this)
     .Load(Uri.parse(valueImage))
     .Apply(RequestOptions.CircleCropTransform()).Into(imageView);
```

The import statement is to put into the app module gradle file (app/build.gradle)

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: You don't need to. The `Load()` method from Glide take care of it by itself ! That's why it's so easy to use :)

Comment: And you need to import Glide into your project. 
I edited my post with the import statement.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2FIMG_20190209_162806.jpg (No such file or directory)

Comment: Can you post the value of your `valueImage` ?

Comment: content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2FIMG_20190209_162806.jpg

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider from ProcessRecord{554b889 14152:com.silkway.test/u0a176} (pid=14152, uid=10176) that is not exported from UID 10032

Comment: Check this, you have to ask permission to read the gallery : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722591/3780625

Comment: W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored

Comment: It's a setup problem, check here : http://sjudd.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html#gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try Glide for your requirement

Import **glide** using `gradle`

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
```

Then set image to imageview using this method

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(valueImage)))
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Image is not found!!!  maybe there is mistake in adding image. Do I need to encode or decode Uri before adding to data?

Comment: Please check if valueImage is not empty before loading imageview