# Create folder in internal storage in android using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a folder in the internal storage of an android device where I can save my `.csv` files. But I am unable to create a folder in the internal storage.

**Below is my code snippet for creating the folder**

```
fun getStorageDirectory(): File {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
        val f = File(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath + "/Afolder/")
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdirs()
        return f
    } else {
        val f = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/Afolder/")
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdirs()
        return f
    }
}
```

*and this is the permissions I used in my manifest.*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: But did you get the *runtime permission* that allows you to write outside the world?

Comment: no sir i am new to android programming how can i do that?

Comment: Just use https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322136/2413303 (specifically `checkPermissionForExternalStorage()` and `requestPermissionForExternalStorage`)

Comment: return if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
            File(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath + pathMedia).apply {
                if (!this.exists())
                mkdirs() }
        } else {
            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + pathMedia).apply {
                if (!this.exists())
                mkdirs() }
        }