# Exception occurred while executing 'kill'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

when I try to run kill in the terminal it results in this error even after I gave the permission in AndroidManifest

PS C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\andfun-kotlin-dessert-pusher-Step.04-Exercise-Add-the-lifecycle-library> adb shell am kill com.example.android.dessertpusher

Exception occurred while executing 'kill':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: killBackgroundProcesses() from pid=17682, uid=2000 requires android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.killBackgroundProcesses(ActivityManagerService.java:4814)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runKill(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:1142)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:228)
at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:11450)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:936)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:820)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:5220)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3149)
at com.android.server.am.OppoActivityManagerService.onTransact(OppoActivityManagerService.java:169)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1166)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1130)

//AndroidManifest:

Comment: AndroidManifest: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.dessertpusher">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"></uses-permission>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android marshmallow request permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)