# How to use StorageStatsManager.queryStatsForPackage on Android O?

Tags: android, storage, android-8.0-oreo

### Background

Before Android O, in order to get an app size, you had to have a special permission for it, and use a hidden API.

### The problem

Such a solution won't work anymore, but instead, Google provides an official API that's less granular: [**queryStatsForPackage**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/StorageStatsManager.html#queryStatsForPackage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.UserHandle)) , which returns [**StorageStats**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/StorageStats.html) object.

However, I can't find any information of how to use it.

As opposed to the hidden API, which only required the package name of the app, this one also requires "String volumeUuid" and "UserHandle user".

### The questions

1. How do I provide those parameters?
2. What do they mean? Is each of the volumeUuid refer to a different storage (build in storage and real sd-card, for example), and UserHandle is for each user?
3. If #2 is correct, should I really call each of them for each possible value, to get the real total storage the app takes? If so, how?

Comment: The volume UUID would come from `StorageManager` and `StorageVolume`, I assume.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do I get it? And is my guess true it's for each storage type ? It seems it is: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html#getStorageVolumes()

Comment: How do you get *what*? `StorageManager` is a system service, and it has a `getStorageVolumes()` method. `StorageVolume` has a `getUuid()` method.

Comment: regarding `volumeUuid` and as per docs, pass null for default internal storage, though , `user` still unclear, but AFAIK in android each app is considered a User, i am not sure if this can lead to something :)

Comment: Putting null is wrong for the default internal storage (it will crash). I've made a small sample after testing it myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I've found out how to use the new API. I've prepared a small sample of this, fetching some information about the volume storage and of a specific app (this time of the Play Store, but you can change it if needed) :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.vending";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!hasUsageStatsPermission(this))
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY), 1);
        else {
            final Context context = this;
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") final StorageStatsManager storageStatsManager = (StorageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                    final StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
                    final List<StorageVolume> storageVolumes = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
                    final UserHandle user = android.os.Process.myUserHandle();
                    for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
                        final String uuidStr = storageVolume.getUuid();
                        final UUID uuid = uuidStr == null ? StorageManager.UUID_DEFAULT : UUID.fromString(uuidStr);
                        try {
                            Log.d("AppLog", "storage:" + uuid + " : " + storageVolume.getDescription(context) + " : " + storageVolume.getState());
                            Log.d("AppLog", "getFreeBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStatsManager.getFreeBytes(uuid)));
                            Log.d("AppLog", "getTotalBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStatsManager.getTotalBytes(uuid)));
                            Log.d("AppLog", "storage stats for app of package name:" + PACKAGE_NAME + " : ");

                            final StorageStats storageStats = storageStatsManager.queryStatsForPackage(uuid, PACKAGE_NAME, user);
                            Log.d("AppLog", "getAppBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getAppBytes()) +
                                    " getCacheBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getCacheBytes()) +
                                    " getDataBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, storageStats.getDataBytes()));
                        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.M)
    public static boolean hasUsageStatsPermission(Context context) {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/42390614/878126
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            return false;
        AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        final int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName());
        boolean granted = false;
        if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_DEFAULT)
            granted = (context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        else
            granted = (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
        return granted;
    }
}
```

manifest file should have this:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

---

EDIT: note that the part of `UUID.fromString(uuidStr)` could fail for SD-cards, and the reason by Google is [**this**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62982912#comment11):

> Android can't maintain quota-style statistics for public volumes (SD
> card etc.). Apps will need to build size calculation logic themselves.

Sadly, on Android 11, due to the new restrictions of reaching "Android" folder, even this is impossible. Requested here to change it:

@t0m But even with what they wrote, it's not officially impossible to do what they said to do, as storage permission got very restricted on Android 11, not allowing you to reach Android folder properly. Requested to solve this here:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187069982
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187082347

Please consider starring.

Comment: Where can I get `Process.myUserHandle();`?

Comment: @rmanalo From the Android framework API  : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myUserHandle() . Available from API 17

Comment: What worked for me is `android.os.Process.myUserHandle()`.

Comment: @rmanalo That's what I used. It's the link I've provided, too.

Comment: Oh. I think I imported a different `Process` hehehe.

Comment: Did you test your code with SDcard? `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: BFAC-11F4`. Line: `UUID.fromString(uuidStr)`

Comment: @t0m Sadly you are right. I tried to report this to Google too, and got this answer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62982912#comment11 "Android can't maintain quota-style statistics for public volumes (SD card etc.). Apps will need to build size calculation logic themselves." . :(

Comment: @t0m But even with what they wrote, it's not officially impossible to do what they said to do, as storage permission got very restricted on Android 11, not allowing you to reach Android folder properly. Requested to solve this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187069982 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187082347 . Please consider starring.

Comment: Using UUID.fromString is generally wrong here. Volume uuid for SD cards is serial ID of FAT32 (XXXX-XXXX), or longer ID for NTFS-formatted cards. But this doesn't match expected format of UUID (d6cd3775-2746-4593-8bba-755a8711b166).
You can use StorageVolume.getStorageUuid, if it returns non-null, it's safe to use in StorageStatsManager.

Comment: @PointerNull Can you please show a full answer?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach for getting UUID.

To get UUIDs, you can also use StorageManager.getUuidForPath(File path) function.
As to the path, use Context.getFilesDir() and Context.getExternalFilesDirs() to get all possibles directories that an app data will be saved to.

Please note that different path may return the same UUID, so you have to use a hash set to collect unique UUIDs

Comment: Yes but is there any advantage of using this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass null as the VolumeUuid, to get values for the default internal storage, or get specific volumes via the StorageManager system service.

You can get your own UserHandle via Process.myUserHandle().  Other users of the system occur when you give someone a guest login on your device, or when there is an Android for Work profile installed on the device.  I don't think there is a simple way to enumerate all the users that have access to the device.

Comment: About VolumeUuid, this means I do have to go over each of the available storage types, right? About UserHandle, how can I get those of the other users?

Comment: The null passing is wrong (will crash). I've put a sample usage.