# Invalid UUID of storage gained from Android StorageManager?

Tags: android, storage, uuid, android-8.0-oreo

I lost whole day fighting with something trivial, but now I just give up and need your help.

In new Oreo API for reading app code/data/cache/ size we need storage UUID ([StorageStatsManager.queryStatsForUid(UUID storageUuid, 
                int uid)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/StorageStatsManager.html#queryStatsForUid(java.util.UUID,%20int))).

The storage UUID is possible to fetch from [StorageManager.getStorageVolumes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html#getStorageVolumes()) which returns list of all storages which contains also the UUIDs.

**And there the problem begins:** The UUID from returned list is in String format while [StorageStatsManager.queryStatsForUid(UUID storageUuid, 
                int uid)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/StorageStatsManager.html#queryStatsForUid(java.util.UUID,%20int)) requires UUID object - nothing simplier - there exist method [UUID.fromString(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#fromString(java.lang.String)) which converts it in a while.. but wait, the UUID value from StorageManager list is incompatibile with UUID parser - **WHAT?!** I've checked on 2 devices (one with Oreo and one with Nougat), both with external memory and for each device I get 2 storages:

1. Internal device memory with UUID equals "null" - thats fine as this is described in documentation
2. External card storage with UUID value in format like "4012-1A4B" what is **invalid UUID format** and causes UUID.fromString throws IllegalArgumentException.

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong and how should I get UUID for external storage? Or just new API [StorageStatsManager.queryStatsForUid(UUID storageUuid, 
                int uid)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/StorageStatsManager.html#queryStatsForUid(java.util.UUID,%20int)) is useless as we are unable to get storage UUID?

---

FYI:

Whats more there is another StackOverflow question where usage of this API is marked as correct solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708209/1946366 what makes me even more frustrated...

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/44837112/115145

Comment: The same problem. The output is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 70DA-3A8D
 at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:194)
 at android.os.storage.StorageManager.convert(StorageManager.java:2091)
 at android.os.storage.StorageManager.getUuidForPath(StorageManager.java:763)

 so this method return also invalid UUID.

Comment: did you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this is raised already bug on Android:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62982912
so I think that my questions is unanswerable.

Comment: I read through the chain of 3 related issues starting with the one you linked. It does look like a platform issue. However! It seems strange and I was skeptical about it, but the answer from @3c71 really seems to work. Go figure :-)

Answer (score 7):

Actually the fromString(uuid_string) takes a "long" UUID (with like 4 or 8 parts can't remember exactly).

However the following works perfectly:

```
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(sv.getUuid().getBytes());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the **application Info** of each package **has Storage Volume UUID** on which this application is being hosted.

You can get it by ,

```
ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packagename, 0);
StorageStats storageStats = storageStatsManager.queryStatsForUid(ai.storageUuid, uid);
```

This is [introduced in Oreo Version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html)