# Android 10 emulator - unable to uninstall apps due to Invalid UUID string

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-10.0

I'm trying to figure out if it's just me. 
On latest Android Studio and Emulator, a stock Android 10 (API 29) image is not able to uninstall apps due to the exception

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity}: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 1BE9-1809
```

[image]

Any hint would be welcome, please note

- uninstalling through ADB `adb uninstall` works as expected, but I need to uninstall through standard drag-n-drop
- already took a look at this SO thread ([Invalid UUID of storage gained from Android StorageManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589109/invalid-uuid-of-storage-gained-from-android-storagemanager)) that leads to believe it's because of the naming of the virtual SD (but I can't create an instance without such SD, at least from Android Studio) [image]

Full stacktrace:

```
6392-6392/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.packageinstaller, PID: 6392
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 1BE9-1809
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 1BE9-1809
    at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:194)
    at android.os.storage.StorageManager.convert(StorageManager.java:2290)
    at com.android.packageinstaller.handheld.UninstallAlertDialogFragment.getAppDataSizeForUser(UninstallAlertDialogFragment.java:78)
    at com.android.packageinstaller.handheld.UninstallAlertDialogFragment.getAppDataSize(UninstallAlertDialogFragment.java:114)
    at com.android.packageinstaller.handheld.UninstallAlertDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(UninstallAlertDialogFragment.java:179)
    at android.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:417)
    at android.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1351)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1303)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2431)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2210)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2166)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2067)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3057)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3004)
    at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:184)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7809)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dumb workaround: delete/rename `sdcard.img` in emulator instance so that it cannot be mounted anymore ie. `rm ~/.android/avd/Pixel_3a_API_29.avd/sdcard.img`

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

Remove/Delete the `sdcard` File in the `.avd` folder of the running emulator

> Goto > C:\Users\some_name.android\avd\your_emulator_folder.avd\sdcard