# Return to app immediately when user has granted the manage external storage permission on Android - Non-deprecated way

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am making an android app that needs the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission (and the read/write permission before android 11). The app requests the permission the first time it starts (using the code of the accepted answer from [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/62782648/android-11-scoped-storage-permissions)).

However, when the user provides the permission they have to manually press the back button to return to the app so it can continue its flow.
I have a file manager app on my phone that returns to the app automatically once the permission is granted. So I am looking for a way to implement this in my app as well, preferably using the new method google suggest instead of the now deprecated `startActivityForResult`

The app I mention is available on playstore [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager)

### What I tried?

Replaced the `startActivityForResult` using `ActivityResultLauncher`, which is the way google recommends, because `startActivityForResult` is now deprecated, but it didn't really change the app's behavior/solve the problem. In fact, it seems to be receiving a rejected result whether the user accepts it or not.

Comment: "I have a file manager app and thus would like to return to the app automatically once the permission is granted" -- being a file manager does not change the fact that Android no longer allows apps in the background to affect the foreground UI very much.

Comment: @CommonsWare that is the product of an edit of another member on my question. What I wanted to write(which I have now wrote and hopefully won't be edited again) is that the app in the playstore (which is not mine) already implements what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching more thoroughly I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445695/android-navigate-back-to-application-from-android-settings) post and I used part 3) of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47583863/20867750) answer, which seems to be doing the trick. I also tried replacing the `startActivityForResult` with the `ActivityResultLauncher` that Google recommends and it works fine. So the final code is:

1. Paste this code on the start of MainActivity(or in the activity you want), just after the properties' declarations:

   ```
   Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable checkSettingOn = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                return;
            } else {
                if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                    //You have the permission, re-launch MainActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                    return;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
            }
        }
    };
   ```
2. After this, create an ActivityResultLauncher, which will handle the user's denial part:

   ```
   ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> storageLauncher =registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
                if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
                    //DO STH IF USER DENIES
        }
    });
   ```
3. When asking for the permission you then start the handler:

   ```
    try {
                    Intent storageIntentTry = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    storageIntentTry.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                    storageIntentTry.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                    storageLauncher.launch(storageIntentTry);
                    handler.postDelayed(checkSettingOn, 1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Intent storageIntentCatch = new Intent();
                    storageIntentCatch.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    storageLauncher.launch(storageIntentCatch);
                    handler.postDelayed(checkSettingOn, 1000);
                }
   ```

(Ignore names of intents - can be anything that makes sense)